# PostgreSQL: Select data from another table by elements of an array and then display in order

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, unnest

I have a table with a collection of parts. These parts have an id and a serial number provided by the manufacturer. Parts are put together to build an assembly and the order which the parts are assembled matters. When this assembly is made, a new part is created which goes into a new table with an array which points to the first table with the ids in order. In other words:

Table "**process.parts**":

| id | serial_no |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PART_A01 |
| 2 | PART_A02 |
| 3 | PART_A03 |
| 4 | PART_A04 |
| 5 | PART_A05 |
| 6 | PART_A06 |

Table "**process.assemblies**":

| id | assembly_order |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {3, 6, 1} |
| 2 | {5, 2, 4} |

I need to select an assembly from Table 2 and display it in order of assembly. In other words, selection of assembly 1 should display:

| output |
| --- |
| PART_A03 |
| PART_A06 |
| PART_A01 |

The SQL command I am using to select the parts is as follows:

```
SELECT id, serial_no
FROM process.parts
WHERE id IN (SELECT unnest(assembly_order) FROM process.assemblies WHERE id = 1);
```

This script does not preserve the order from the array. Is there a way to modify this to loop through the elements of the array to preserve order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the schema you currently have, you can:

- select your needed ids
- unnest the corresponding "*assembly_order*" field
- join with the parts table on matching ids

In order to keep the order of the array elements unaltered, you use the `WITH ORDINALITY` clause, that allows you to retrieve the index alongside your unnested array.

```
SELECT cte.id
FROM       (SELECT assembly_order FROM assemblies WHERE id = 1) a 
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(a.assembly_order) WITH ORDINALITY cte(id, idx) 
INNER JOIN parts p
        ON p.id = cte.id
ORDER BY cte.idx
```

If you want all ids, you can use the whole table in step 1 instead a selection of it.

**Output**:

| serial_no |
| --- |
| PART_A03 |
| PART_A06 |
| PART_A01 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9jBxPbRMTCBHNzvZh2gDJC/2).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you don't want to hear this now, but this is not the right way to organize this data.  There should be a `parts` table, an `assembly` table, and an `assembly_order` table that links the two, with one step per row.  Like:

process.assembly_order

| part | step | assembly |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 |

Now you can do

```
SELECT part,assembly FROM parts,assembly_order WHERE assembly_order.part = parts.id ORDER BY part, step;
```